# Decompile scala's .class file in Android Studio generates .java file?

Tags: java, android, scala

As first thing, I don't know Scala so well and neither .class files in details (from both java and scala).

I'm porting [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org) on Android. One of the libraries used in the project  is `flink-runtime.jar` and contains this Scala file:

`runtime/minicluster/LocalFlinkMiniCluster.scala`

When Intellij IDEA decompile the `LocalFlinkMiniCluster.class` contained the `.jar` file, the correct and origal `LocalFlinkMiniCluster.scala` is displayed.

This doesn't happen in Android studio. Instead a java code is returned with the message :

> Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 50.0 (Java 6)

To make you understand better what I'm talking about, this is the method `setMemory` from the original .scala file:

```
  def setMemory(config: Configuration): Unit = {
    // set this only if no memory was pre-configured
    if (config.getInteger(ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_SIZE_KEY, -1) == -1) {

      val bufferSize: Int = config.getInteger(
        ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_SEGMENT_SIZE_KEY,
        ConfigConstants.DEFAULT_TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_SEGMENT_SIZE)

      val bufferMem: Long = config.getLong(
        ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_NETWORK_NUM_BUFFERS_KEY,
        ConfigConstants.DEFAULT_TASK_MANAGER_NETWORK_NUM_BUFFERS) * bufferSize.toLong

      val numTaskManager = config.getInteger(
        ConfigConstants.LOCAL_NUMBER_TASK_MANAGER,
        ConfigConstants.DEFAULT_LOCAL_NUMBER_TASK_MANAGER)

      val memoryFraction = config.getFloat(
        ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_FRACTION_KEY,
        ConfigConstants.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER_MEMORY_FRACTION)

      // full memory size
      var memorySize: Long = EnvironmentInformation.getSizeOfFreeHeapMemoryWithDefrag

      // compute the memory size per task manager. we assume equally much memory for
      // each TaskManagers and each JobManager
      memorySize /= numTaskManager + 1 // the +1 is the job manager

      // for each TaskManager, subtract the memory needed for memory buffers
      memorySize -= bufferMem
      memorySize = (memorySize * memoryFraction).toLong
      memorySize >>>= 20 // bytes to megabytes
      config.setLong(ConfigConstants.TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_SIZE_KEY, memorySize)
    }
  }
```

This is the java version created by Android Studio (what the hell is that asian symbol?):

```
public void setMemory(Configuration config) {
    if(config.getInteger("taskmanager.memory.size", -1) == -1) {
        int bufferSize = config.getInteger("taskmanager.memory.segment-size", '耀');
        long bufferMem = config.getLong("taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers", 2048L) * (long)bufferSize;
        int numTaskManager = config.getInteger("local.number-taskmanager", 1);
        float memoryFraction = config.getFloat("taskmanager.memory.fraction", 0.7F);
        long memorySize = EnvironmentInformation.getSizeOfFreeHeapMemoryWithDefrag();
        memorySize /= (long)(numTaskManager + 1);
        memorySize -= bufferMem;
        memorySize = (long)((float)((double)memorySize * (double)memoryFraction));
        memorySize >>>= 20;
        config.setLong("taskmanager.memory.size", memorySize);
    }

}
```

And obviously the execution of the two methods have different effects.

Please, can you help me to understand why this happens and how can I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The Asian symbol, according to an online dictionary, means "to shine; to glitter; to sparkle". Other than that I don't know how to help and not sure if what you are doing is called "porting".

Comment: +1 for the really useful information about the meaning of the asian symbol. But I still need to understand why this happens.

Comment: are you sure that Intellij Idea decompiles .class file?  How would the comments appear? As you can see in java version constants are inlined so I would guess the asian symbol is, after converting to int equal to `ConfigConstants.DEFAULT_TASK_MANAGER_MEMORY_SEGMENT_SIZE`

Comment: Why you are decompiling the class files and not using the flink sources instead? Another reason could be: IntelliJ used the source from the dependency and this might be not set up the same way in Android Studio. That's why you see the original sources in IntelliJ whereas Android Studio decompiles the class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem by myself: the Scala plugin is installed by default (or there is an option anyway in the wizard) on IntelliJ. In Android Studio instead it has to be installed manually.